# What is the easiest way to write a list of Ints to a binary file?

Tags: haskell

My Haskell is a little rusty at the moment. I have a list of Ints I want to write to a file. I see mention of ways to do this with bytestring builders etc., but can't find a simple example. Can someone help me get this simple task done without me having to research a bunch of libraries? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `binary`:

```
import Data.Binary
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

writeIntsToFile :: FilePath -> [Int] -> IO ()
writeIntsToFile fp is = B.writeFile fp ser
  where ser = encode is
```

Notice this uses the default encoding for list and the default encoding for Int.  As a results your file format will be a 64 bit field indicating the number of elements followed by that many 64 bit values for each `Int`.  All these values are in big endian.

Comment: How would I get this into 32 bit little endian?